# Is there a way to reverse engineer a stored procedure and retrieve table and column names without executing the code?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure in my SQL Server database, and I need to collect the table and column names used in it without actually executing the code.  Is there an easier way to reverse engineer the stored procedure and retrieve the table and column names without executing the code?

I appreciate any help or suggestions on this matter. Thank you.

I know that I can use sp_depends to get the dependent objects of the stored procedure, but it only returns the names of the tables and not the column names.

Comment: Right click -> modify, will show you the procedure script without executing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure is encrypted or internally not implemented in sql (e.g. .NET C#) there is no chance for reverse engeneering. If this is not the case the system stored procedure sp_helptext is your friend.

```
exec sp_helptext procname        -- procedure resides in standard schema, normally dbo
exec sp_helptext 'test.procname' -- procedure resides in schema test
```

In SSMS you could also navigate to  -> Programmability -> Stored Procedures. Here you have to localize the procedure you are interested in and press right-mouse-button for the context menu. Here you have to choose 'Script Stored Procedure as'. But internally the sp_helptext is used too.